# Flutter Field has not been initialized. error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, initialization

This is exactly what happened: I am making a shopping application, but when I list the file from which I have the information of the products, it gives a late error. There is no problem when the urunList part is only if value, but when I add else if I get this error. I tried the null method, but this time I get a typo in the children:urunList section and it doesn't specify the reason.

[image: this my code]

Comment: Ur initializing is fine but U can't declare children like that in GridView,count. try this instead.   children: List.generate(urunList.length, (index) => urunList[index];  }

Comment: @JB Jason 
can you provide any proof of your statement? that's a normal way to provide a list of widgets.

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-gridview#:~:text=GridView.-,count(),number%20of%20rows%20and%20columns.

Comment: What if `widget.kategori` is not any of those strings?  There is no `else` to fall back to, and `urunliste` will remain uninitialized.  Also consider not using `late` and initializing it to some default value (such as an empty `List`).

Comment: And in the future, please post code, not screenshots of code.